# Changing elements in lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created an application in ruby on rails, and it has a variable with the following content:

```
[<Node id: 474, value: 1>, <Node id: 475, value: 2>, <Node id: 465, value: 1>]
```

I wonder how I can change the data of a given attribute, e.g., the id:

before:

```
[<Node id: 474, value: 1>, <Node id: 475, value: 2>, <Node id: 465, value: 1>]
```

then:

```
[<Node id: 1, value: 1>, <Node id: 2, value: 2>, <Node id: 3, value: 1>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
list = [<Node id: 474, value: 1>, <Node id: 475, value: 2>, <Node id: 465, value: 1>]

list.each_with_index do |item, index|
  item.id = index + 1
end
```

However, as this is tagged with RoR I assume you are trying to update the IDs of models stored in the Database. ActiveRecord will not make it easy for you to update the ID as this might break data integrity. A simple call to `save` will not work. If you really want to overwrite the ID, and I advise you against doing it, you will need to use `update_all`.

Comment: It works! I only need to change the variable even without changing the database. Thank you!

Comment: A slight variant (not recommending): `list.each.with_index(1) { |item, index| item.id = index }`.